# How to make Ladda work with angular2 application

Tags: angular, spinner

I am trying to integrate ladda with my angular2 app. I am basically trying to import the library and use the Ladda variable. Angular didnt seems to find that variable. any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

```
declare const Ladda: any;
export class someComponent implements AfterViewInit{
   @ViewChild('scbutton') scbutton: ElementRef;
   l:any;
 ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.l = Ladda.create(this.scbutton.nativeElement);
           }
    }

// u can use this.l.start() and this.l.stop() in ur submit logic
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import Ladda from 'ladda';

export class someComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('yourButton') yourButton: ElementRef;
    l: any;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        this.l = Ladda.create(this.scbutton.nativeElement);
        this.l.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Angular 4+ Ladda module  that implements [angular2-ladda](https://github.com/moff/angular2-ladda).

[Check out Ladda's demo](http://lab.hakim.se/ladda/)